# Why do some books define $\cot x$ as reciprocal of $\tan x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I believe $\cot x$ should be defined as $ \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ and not as $\dfrac{1}{\tan x}$

Because  $\cot x$ and $\dfrac{1}{\tan x}$ aren't even the same function,  they have different domains.

So for instance we know $\cot (π/2) = 0$ but $\dfrac{1}{ \tan (π/2)}$ is not even defined.

Am I correct in believing this?

Comment: You are right about this.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ty, most of the books, in fact all the sources I could find define $\cot x$ as reciprocal of $\tan x$. Wonder why.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:  I was going to say something similar, though I think you meant cot$\theta=\frac {\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Well, that was an embarrassing error.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the authors of the texts that define $\cot\theta$ as the reciprocal of $\tan\theta$ are doing so for trigonometric ratios rather than trigonometric functions.  Since trigonometric ratios are defined for acute angles and it is not possible for $\tan\theta = 0$ when $\theta$ is acute, such a definition does not present a problem until you consider trigonometric functions.  For trigonometric functions $f(x) = \cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ is defined whenever $\sin x \neq 0 \implies x \neq n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: by analytic continuation they have the same domain, I think this is the reason to state both as equivalent expressions (under analytic continuation considerations, of course)